# Some posts in google search results have "avatar" writing in the title

Tags: wordpress

When I search in google for posts from a blog, some results contain "avatar" in the title.
[google search link](https://www.google.de/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Jura-News%3a+Aktuelle+Entwicklungen+im+e-Trade-Recht&oq=Jura-News%3a+Aktuelle+Entwicklungen+im+e-Trade-Recht&gs_l=hp.3...4120.4120.0.4603.1.1.0.0.0.0.156.156.0j1.1.0.les;..0.0...1c.1.5.psy-ab.c5vqrSTFTD4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.43287494,d.Yms&fp=aef84b2676c9749c&biw=1024&bih=668)
If you open the link you will see that the 4th result has "avatar" written in the title, but the 3rd and the 4th.
Can anybody suggest any solution how to remove this thing?
Thanks.

Comment: seems like it's the alt tag of the image that is in the h1 element

Comment: shall I delete the tag?

Comment: Change from <h1> tag to something else, or move the image out of the h1 field.

Comment: In which file is this part? because I'm looking in wordpress editor and can't find it.

Comment: The thing is that google shows not every post title with "avatar" in it. I tried to search with yahoo and I didn't face such problem.